# Cannot Instantiate listener guiceListner, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, guice

I am trying to create a RESTFul web service using Jersey on Google App Engine. I am trying to add Guice for Dependency injection.

I have addeded the following in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.archit.guice.GuiceListener</listener-class>
</listener>    

<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have also defined a class GuiceListener in the package com.archit.guice.

The code in the class GuiceListener is:

```
public class GuiceListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    private ServletContext servletContext = null;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
    } 
    
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new GuiceServletModule(),
                new MainShiroWebModule(servletContext), ShiroWebModule.guiceFilterModule());
    }
}
```

When I deploy the app to appengine and call any REST API, I get 404 error and the error log provided in appengine is:

```
Could not instantiate listener com.archit.guice.GuiceListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.archit.guice.GuiceListener
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-08b248c3657c5fb3(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1101)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the reason for ClassNotFoundException even though I have define the class.
I have tried clean build by using

```
mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was a really silly mistake. There was nothing wrong with the class GuiceListener, but in some other class in my package, the package name was incorrect, due to which maven was not actually builing the .class file (even though it was not giving any errors while building). After correcting the package name in that other class, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same with me. If you followed Google instructions you may fall in the same error than me. In `web.xml` write:

> `<listener-class>com.example.echo.EchoGuiceListener</listener-class>`

instead of

> `<listener-class>com.example.skeleton.EchoGuiceListener</listener-class>`